# почему когда сложный скрипт запускаешь через браузер, то сайт виснет пока скрипт не выполнится

Tags: php, консоль

почему когда сложный скрипт запускаешь через браузер, то сайт виснет пока скрипт не выполнится, а если через cli то скрипт работает параллельно, а сайт доступен?

Кто-то может объяснить как это работает и почему так происходит? И можно ли как-то скрипт который запускается через браузер, что бы работал также, как  и при запуске через cli, что бы сайт не записал в момент выполнения? Может нужно в отдельном потоке запустить? и можно ли так?